# any idea how to find the code behind of this form "inventory item", computing "Total Value"

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

any idea how to find the code behind of this form "inventory item", i just wanna figure out what's the formula used to compute total value highlighted in red ), image below.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Total Value` field is a NetSuite system field showing the value on hand of that inventory item.  Given that you are using a Costing Method of Average, the calculation for the total value will be `Quantity On Hand` * `Average Cost`.  This should reflect the balance sheet impact of that item (i.e.: the asset valuation).

If for some reason you or someone else at your company has hidden the NetSuite system field and created a custom field with the label `Total Value`, you could check the following places (this is general to all custom fields):

1. First check the custom field itself at Customization > Lists, Records, & Fields > Item Fields.  Find the custom field you need to check and look in the Validation & Defaulting tab.  If either the Default Value or Search field is filled, this is probably the value of your custom field comes from.  Then check in the Sourcing & Filtering tab in case it's sourced from another field on a different record.
2. Next, go to Customization > Scripting > Scripted Records.  Click on Inventory Part (or the relevant record type for other fields) and review the scripts, forms and workflows for anything that could be related.  If you don't know whether a script could be setting the value you're looking for, you can navigate to the script concerned and search it for the internal id of the field.